# What is this PCB spark-gap on common-mode-choke for?

Tags: pcb-design

I came across this PCB spark-gap on the coil legs of a common-mode-choke.

[image]

As far as I know, there needs to be some high voltage between two points for a spark to occur. Assuming there is a 1mm gap, there needs to be 1 kV of voltage difference.

Now, since a coil is almost short-circuit (0.8 ohms in this case), ***what is the purpose of the spark-gap in this case?*** Is it there in case of there is some kind of failure on the coil?

The circuit and the layout are taken from [this application note from ROHM](http://www.rohm.com/documents/11308/2450231/B3_BM1P061FJEVK-001.pdf), for a flyback circuit.

Answer (score 4):

A coil has low impedance for low-frequency signals and high impedance for high-frequency signals. So ESD discharges would be blocked without the spark gap.

(A common-mode choke is designed to allow differential-mode signals of any frequency through, but ESD discharges and other noise would not be differential.)

Answer (score 3):

If you get some sort of power surge, whether it be ESD, a lightning strike, or something of that sort, the choke (an inductor) will "block" the surge, since current in an inductor cannot change instantaneously. Effectively it will act as a large resistor. The spark will jump between the gap contacts instead. Depending on the size of the choke, this may also be used to limit voltage spikes when current is removed from the choke, but I can't say I've ever seen spark gaps used for this purpose. Usually you see freewheel diodes.

Comment: Before the spark-gaps, there is a capacitor. Let's say the lightning found its way through the spark-gaps, after that there is an another capacitor. What would you think about the way current will want to travel?